# Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): createPromise is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create new function from obj I have converted to string I get this error

> Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): createPromise is not defined

```
export const transToObj = strObj => JSON.parse(strObj, (key, val) => {
  // Make sure the current value is not null (is a string)
  // and that the first characters are "function"
  if (typeof val === 'string' && val.indexOf('function') === 0) {
    // Isolate the argument names list
    const start = val.indexOf('(') + 1;
    const end = val.indexOf(')');
    const argListString = val.substring(start, end).split(',');

    // Isolate the body of the function
    const body = val.substr(val.indexOf('{'), val.length - end + 1);

    // Construct a new function using the argument names and body
    // stored in the string:
    return new Function(argListString, body);
  }
  // Non-function property, just return the value
  return val;
});

const refreshToken = () => {
      const kc = transToObj(localStorage.getItem('kc'));
      kc.updateToken(30).success().error(() => {
        window.location.reload(true);
      });
    };

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-await
    const getNewToken = async () => await refreshToken();
```

[image: screenshot from error]

Comment: what makes you think this code snippet is causing the error? have you added console.logs to make sure `argListString` is being built properly?

Comment: I added screenshot from error

Comment: can you see the value of `body` before calling `new Function`? Maybe it's invalid. Try putting a `try`/`catch` block around `new Function` also so you can capture the error and recover.

Comment: `refreshToken` doesn't return a Promise. why do you `await` on it?

Comment: it would be helpful to see the text value of `kc` that's being parsed.

Comment: refreshToken caused this error it seem object change after being parsed

Comment: Is there any other way to store object with methods in localstorage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207489/discussion-between-muhammad-fared-and-always-learning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be in the fact that you're using `await` on `refreshToken` but it doesn't return a `Promise`. The error message is complaining that `createPromise` is not defined but we don't see any code that tries to call that function, so I'm guessing that it's used by the `kc.updateToken()` function.

When using `async/await` you need to work with `Promises` througout.

If `kc` is a `KeyCloak` object, then `updateToken` returns a `Promise` and you can simply return it without using `.success()` or `.error()` like this:

```
const refreshToken = () => {
  const kc = transToObj(localStorage.getItem('kc'));
  return kc.updateToken(30)  // return the promise and let others await on it
    .catch(e => {
      window.location.reload(true);
    });
};
```

Comment: yeah it's keycloak but when store object return it from keycloak in variable  working fine but after saved it in localstorage by above function i get this error

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how i solve it

I used npm package call @react-keycloak/web and this library helps me with provider have keycloak instance so i have all functions i need in all app without converting  functions and lose the adapter